# Is the QuickDraw with Google neural net a convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, image-recognition, convolutional-neural-networks

Does anyone know, or can we deduce or infer with high probability from its characteristics, whether the neural network used on this site

https://quickdraw.withgoogle.com/

is a type of convolutional neural network (CNN)?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn

Comment: @RonakPoriya Is the link based on Google Quick Draw code or part of the project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe they don't use CNNs. The most important reason why it's because they have more information than a regular image: time. The input they receive is a sequence of (x,y,t) as you draw on the screen, which they refer as "ink". This gives them the construction of the image for free, which a CNN would have to deduce by itself.

They tried two approaches. Their currently most successful approach does the following:

- Detect parts of the ink that are candidates of being a character
- Use a FeedForward Neural Network to do character recognition on those candidates
- Use beam search and a language model to find most the most likely combination of results that results into a word

Their second approach is using an LSTM (a type of Recurrent Neural Network) end-to-end. In their paper they say this was better in a couple languages.

**Source**: I was an intern in Google's handwriting team in summer 2015 (on which I believe quickdraw is based), but the techniques I explained can be found in [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7478642).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that it used convolution and recurrent neural network. There is [a dataset webpage used in Quick Draw project](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/quickdraw-dataset) and it led to [Recurrent Neural Networks for Drawing Classification GitHub page](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw.md). The GitHub link showed the neural network structure as well.

Here is [the neural network structure from the GitHub page](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/195ad70dcef32fe44a143a8b65609d19622271052256cd7c6e904c44caf4ac6c/68747470733a2f2f7777772e74656e736f72666c6f772e6f72672f696d616765732f717569636b647261775f6d6f64656c2e706e67):
[image]

The current Quick Draw might be evolved from the neural network structure at the GitHub because the webpage written in 2020.